# facebook API photos pagination not returning "previous" link

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, pagination

Referencing to the following article :

http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-user-photo-albums-browser-using-facebook-graph-api/77/

I am creating a User Photo Albums Browser Using Facebook Graph API. Everything is working fine except the `Pagination`. The issue is `$facebook->api` not returning "previous" paging link.

Following is my code :

```
$params = array();
    $params['offset'] = 0;
    if (isset($_GET['offset']))
        $params['offset'] = $_GET['offset']+25;
    if (isset($_GET['limit']))
        $params['limit'] = $_GET['limit'];
    $params['fields'] = 'name,source,images';
    $params = http_build_query($params, null, '&');        
    $album_photos = $facebook->api("/{$_GET['id']}/photos?$params");

    if (isset($album_photos['paging'])) {
        if (isset($album_photos['paging']['next'])) {
            $next_url = parse_url($album_photos['paging']['next'], PHP_URL_QUERY) . "&id=" . $_GET['id'];
        }
        if (isset($album_photos['paging']['previous'])) {
            $pre_url = parse_url($album_photos['paging']['previous'], PHP_URL_QUERY) . "&id=" . $_GET['id'];
        }
    }
```

Here if I am printing :

```
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($$album_photos['paging']);
        exit;
```

The resulting is showing link this :

```
[paging] => Array
        (
            [next] => https://graph.facebook.com/133750480034063/photos?fields=name,source,images&offset=0&limit=25&after=MzI0ODMwNTYwOTI2MDUz
        )
```

Which means `paging` array returning link only for `next` not for `previous`.

How can I get the `previous` link.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The resulting is showing link this :

```
[next] => https://graph.facebook.com/133750480034063/photos?
          fields=name,source,images&offset=0&limit=25&after=MzI0ODMwNTYwOTI2MDUz
```

> Which means paging array returning link only for next not for previous.

With an **offset of 0**, there obviously *are no* previous data sets to retrieve.

Facebook changed this end of last year, saying that they are now only returning previous/next URLs if there actually *is* more data to fetch. (Not for all connections, but some.)

And this is a good thing, because it saves developers from making another time-consuming HTTP request just to find out there is no more data.

So, use them if they are present and you need more data – and if they are not there, just do nothing.